# Display remote Android apps running in LXC to a smartphones

Tags: android, remote-access, vnc, lxc, lxd

I’m currently working on a project where I want to be able to **allow users to access Android apps** *without downloading*.

### Current setup using LXC containers

I’m doing this by running **LXC containers** with **Android OS** installed on a server (remote).

### Desired goal

I’m unable to figure out *how to remote display* these apps (running on remote server, i.e. LXC containers) to client app (running on smartphones).
My main concern is to:

- **minimise latency** and
- allow *normal* apps as well as *video* and *gaming* apps to work

### What I did (*research*)

I’ve researched *VNC*, *Xpra* etc. but can't figure out how to use it for reaching my goal.

---

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Also, is it possible that i can display through web? That means any apps can remotely display in the browser

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could post this as well as **some links** (concrete findings) you have researched (e.g. _why VNC-server on remote is not working with VNC-clients on smartphones?_). Please [edit] and provide some _versions_ of the OS/applications in use.

Comment: Did you try VNC to share the screen between server (LXC) and client (smartphone)? For example see this article on [How to Remote Desktop into a Linux Container](https://www.kiloroot.com/proxmox-ubuntu-server-14-04-tigervnc-how-to-remote-desktop-into-a-linux-container/).

Comment: Yes I’ve looked into VNC in detail. I’ve not implemented it as of yet to be honest. But research about VNC suggests that it might not be able to provide native-like performance. As you know, many android apps like YouTube, Netflix and Facebook contain video content. I’m not sure VNC will be able to handle that.